# How to identify the preceding sibling through xpath in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here is the code after using siblings I'm not able to click on the checkbox. What's wrong with it?

**Code:**

```
checkbox1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("td/nobr/a[text()='192.168.50.120']/../preceding-sibling::td/input[@class='checkbox']")
```

[image: TD]

Comment: Post HTML code in text format here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To select the desired *checkbox* i.e. the `<input>` node referencing the `<a>` node with text as **192.168.50.120** you can use the following solution:

```
checkbox1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td//nobr//a[contains(@href,'nodeinfo?nodeid') and text()='192.168.50.120']//preceding::input[1]")
```

Answer (score 5):

you are not getting the right element, you are trying to get `td`. The correct xpath should be:

```
//td[nobr/a[text()='192.168.50.120']]/preceding-sibling::td/input[@class='checkbox']
```